# cannot pull an object from an array and also at the same time cannot pull value from its nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i have a document given bellow-

```
{
  "_id": {
      "$oid": "61fb6bf71be79c03227d6bbf"
  },
  "id": "17202155",

  "completed": ["cse331", "cse312"],

  "incompleted": [{
      "name": "math",
      "preReq": ["bang", "eng"]
  }, {
      "name": "science",
      "preReq": ["bang", "eng", "math"]
  }, {
      "name": "astronomy",
      "preReq": ["bang", "eng", "science","math"]
  }]
}
```

I want to pull the objejct from the array named "incompleted" where the name:math and also pull "math" from all the "preReq".

in short i want to update the document. And the resulted document -

```
{
  "_id": {
      "$oid": "61fb6bf71be79c03227d6bbf"
  },
  "id": "17202155",

  "completed": ["cse331", "cse312"],

  "incompleted": [{
      "name": "science",
      "preReq": ["bang", "eng"]
  }, {
      "name": "astronomy",
      "preReq": ["bang", "eng", "science"]
  }]
}
```

I used this code-

```
stCourseCompetion_collection.updateOne({id:"17202155"},
             {
                $pull:{
                   "incompleted":{ "name":"math"},
                   "incompleted.$[].preReq":"math"
                }
             }).then(result=>{
                console.log(result);
             })
```

but it does not work.

It give me some error like-

(node:14996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: Updating the path 'incompleted.$[].preReq' would create a conflict at 'incompleted'

```
at F:\senior project\ciu-app-practise\ciu-app-db\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\update.js:80:33
at F:\senior project\ciu-app-practise\ciu-app-db\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:272:25
at handleOperationResult (F:\senior project\ciu-app-practise\ciu-app-db\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:363:9)
at MessageStream.messageHandler (F:\senior project\ciu-app-practise\ciu-app-db\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:479:9)

at MessageStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
at processIncomingData (F:\senior project\ciu-app-practise\ciu-app-db\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
at MessageStream._write (F:\senior project\ciu-app-practise\ciu-app-db\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:731:22) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:14996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

Comment: try `{"id":"17202157"}` instead of `{id:"17202157"}`

Comment: sorry there is mistake in writting the querry. the id was the same (17202155). but the querry does nto works. i got an error which is given.

Comment: error says you have Unhandled promise. first you should catch the errors then fix them.

Comment: Assuming nothing will ever be its own prereq, have you considred using arrayFilters to only update array elements that actually have the prereq you want to remove?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pull from two different arrays at the same time , you need to do it with two commands:

1. Pull  math element from preReq array:

   ```
   db.collection.update({
      id: "17202155"
     },
     {
      $pull: {
      "incompleted.$[].preReq": "math"
     }
     })
   ```

[playground 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7jtlPC-8bQf)

2. Pull the name:"math" element from the incompleted array:

   ```
   db.collection.update({
    id: "17202155"
    },
    {
     $pull: {
     "incompleted": {
      name: "math"
     }
    }
   })
   ```

[playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jytY6J1u2gj)